# attribute 'target' multiversioning cannot be combined with attribute 'always_inline'

Tags: c++, clang, visual-studio-2022

I use clang version 15.0.2 with Visual Studio 2022.
Recently, I upgraded Visual Studio 2022 to the latest version and suddenly my project started getting this error all over.

It only affects my debug build. Release builds and runs fine.
This same project is shared across multiple computers and it only encounters this issue on the computer that upgraded visual studio. My other computer runs an older version of Visual Studio and the debug and release builds work fine.

It seems to focus around rtmintrin.h, which is a header built into the compiler.

What does this error mean and how can it be resolved?

EDIT: Upgrading to Clang 16.0.0 does not resolve the issue.

```
32>In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\include\string:11:
32>In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\include\xstring:14:
32>In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\include\xmemory:13:
32>In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\include\limits:14:
32>In file included from C:\Program Files\LLVM\lib\clang\15.0.2\include\intrin.h:20:
32>C:\Program Files\LLVM\lib\clang\15.0.2\include\rtmintrin.h(36,1): error : attribute 'target' multiversioning cannot be combined with attribute 'always_inline'
32>In file included from C:\Program Files\LLVM\lib\clang\15.0.2\include\x86intrin.h:15:
32>C:\Program Files\LLVM\lib\clang\15.0.2\include\intrin.h(167,6): note: function multiversioning caused by this declaration
```

[image]

[image]

[image]